# how to show and maintain data status only once in angular table row

Tags: html, angular

I have a table where i am showing list of items in table row. I am maintaining item availability by showing red and green circles. That is when item is available it shows in green circle when its not-available it shows red colour. Whenever i am showing item availability it keeps on changing its value. How can i solve this???

*component.html*

```
   <table class="table tabs links">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th>S. No.</th>
   <th>Analytics Name</th>
   <th></th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor=" let item of itemArray[0] | paginate : {itemsPerPage: 
   itemsPerPage, currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: totalItems}; 
      let i = index ">
       <td>{{ (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage + i + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.ItemName }}</td>
        <td><i [ngClass]="itemStateCssClass(item.ItemId)" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
         </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

*component.ts* file

```
    itemStateCssClass(itemId) {
 this.service.itemIdForStatus(itemId).subscribe((res: any) => {
  let itemState;
  let classes;
  let status = res.payload;
  itemState = status.Status;
  switch (itemState) {
    case "notAvailable":
      classes = "fa fa-circle  redColor";
      break;
    case "available":
      classes = "fa fa-circle greenColor";
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  this.statusUpdate = classes
  return classes;
});

return this.statusUpdate;
}
```

*component.scss*

```
.redColor{
 color: #e00c0c;
 }
.greenColor{
color: forestgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a lot of subscribers to get the class of each row, and you are using one local property `statusUpdate` to set its value.

Because `ngClass` works with booleans, you should have your class method return a boolean (or in this case, `Observable<boolean>`) and set the class name based on its value.

Component TS File:

```
// Returns the observable that emits a boolean value.
public itemStateCssClass(itemId) {
  return this.service.itemIdForStatus(itemId)
  .pipe(
    map(res=>status.Status==='available')
  );
}
```

Template HTML file

```
<tr
  *ngFor=" let item of itemArray[0] | paginate : {itemsPerPage: 
   itemsPerPage, currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: totalItems}; 
      let i = index "
>
  <td>{{ (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage + i + 1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.ItemName }}</td>
  <td *ngIf="itemStateCssClass(item.ItemId) | async as available">
    <i class="fa fa-circle" [ngClass]="{'greenColor': available, 'redColor': !available}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The `aync` pipe will subscribe to the observable returned from the method. We then use the boolean to set the conditional class.